# Why won't .trim() work with me?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble getting this bit of javascript to work. Whenever I try it inputs nothing into my div. It just adds ?weight=NumberInputed&measure=lbsOrkgs&submit=Submit to the URL.

```
    <h2>How small must you be to become a black hole?</h2>
    <form name="form1">
        <input id="howMuch" type="number" name="weight" placeholder="How much do you weigh?">
        <input type="radio" name="measure" value="lbs" checked="true">lbs
        <input type="radio" name="measure" value="kgs">kgs
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="calc(); return false;">
    </form>
    <br/>
    <div id="insert"><div/>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="Text/JavaScript">
        function calc() {
            var speedOfLight = 299792458.0;
            var gravityConstantYoctometre = 66738400000000.0;
            var finalHeight = 0.0;
            var weight = document.form1.weight.value;
            var measure = document.form1.measure.value;
            measure = measure.trim();

            if (measure !== "kgs"){
                weight *= 0.4536;
            }

            finalHeight = (4.0 * gravityConstantYoctometre * weight)/Math.pow(speedOfLight,2);
            finalHeight = (finalHeight).toFixed(5);
            var message = '<em>You would have to be ' + finalHeight + ' yoctometres (1 metre x 10<sup>-24</sup>) tall before you would become a black hole.</em>';
            document.getElementById('insert').innerHTML = message;
        }
    </script>
```

Without the .trim() function, it executes perfectly, except for the fact that it will not recognize measure equaling anything resembling 'lbs' or 'kgs'. What is happening here?

Comment: What do you expect that trim to do? You look like you are getting measure from a radio button which means you know that there should be no whitespace around it, etc. As for why it fails, no idea offhand. Any javascript errors in console?

Comment: I always wondered how many yoctometers tall I'd have to be before I become a black hole...

Comment: Alright, I fixed the syntax error, still no luck. I want to trim the measure because when I look at my code in a browser it seems to add whitespace to my two radio button values. I don't know why. I figured that might be why the if wouldn't compute, so I added the .trim(). Also, no javascript errors after I fixed the brace.

Comment: With subtraction (`-`), multiplication (`*`) and division (`/`), the operands are converted to `Number` for the operation. Conversion from `String` to `Number` ignores leading and trailing whitespace, so you can remove the line with `.trim()`. As for debugging, read [Secrets of the Browser Developer Tools](http://devtoolsecrets.com/).

Comment: Because `document.form1.measure` returns an HTMLCollection (it references a radio button group, not a single control), which doesn't have a `value` property. So you are calling `undefined.trim()`.

Comment: Oh, and do not name a form control `submit` as it will mask the form's submit method.

Comment: Oh, cool. How do I convert the HTML collection to a string then?

Comment: Never mind, Ani fixed that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/dJJjr/1/

```
 function calc() {
        var speedOfLight = 299792458.0;
        var gravityConstantYoctometre = 66738400000000.0;
        var finalHeight = 0.0;
        var weight = document.getElementById("howMuch").value;
        var radio = document.getElementsByName('measure');

        var measure = ""
        for(var i =0; i< radio.length; i++)
        {
            if(radio[i].checked)
               measure = radio[i].value;
        }
        measure = measure.trim();
        alert(measure); //For testing purpose
        alert(weight);   //For testing purpose
        if (measure !== "kgs"){
            weight *= 0.4536;
        }

        finalHeight = (4.0 * gravityConstantYoctometre * weight)/Math.pow(speedOfLight,2);
        finalHeight = (finalHeight).toFixed(5);
        var message = '<em>You would have to be ' + finalHeight + ' yoctometres (1 metre x 10<sup>-24</sup>) tall before you would become a black hole.</em>';
        document.getElementById('insert').innerHTML = message;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, explain the error and how to fix it.